# Pushing objects into Object Array - Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Having trouble with some code here. Building an application but stumbling over how to work with array objects. I provided the code above NgInit{}. And provided the TS error I am getting in Xcode.

## Full component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Ticker } from '../TickerType'; 
import { ConversionService } from '../Conversion.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {resultsType} from './resultsTypeInterface';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-contents',
  templateUrl: './contents.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contents.component.scss']
})
export class ContentsComponent implements OnInit{

//Will hold the data from the JSON file


  // Variables for front end
 cryptoSelected : boolean = false;
 regSelected : boolean = false;
 step2AOptions : any[] = [
      {name: "make a selection..."},
      {name: "Bitcoin"},
      {name: "DASH"},
      {name: "Etherium"}  
    ]; // step2AOptions
 step2BOptions : any[] = [
      {name: "make a selection..."},
      {name: "CAD"},
      {name: "USD"} 
    ]; // step2BOptions
 step2Selection: string;
 holdings: number = 10;

coins: any[] = ["BTC_ETH", "BTC_DASH"];
ticker: Ticker[];
coinResults: resultsType[] =[]; 
currencyExchange:any[] = [];   

  constructor( private conversionService: ConversionService ) { 

  }
```

## Error

```
Argument of type '{ name: string; amount: any; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'resultsType'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type '{ name: string; amount: any; }[]'.
```

This is happening in the code below. What I am trying to do is push this objects into an Object Array so I can access properties of like.

```
console.log(coinsResults[0].name);
```

## Code

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.conversionService.getFullTicker().subscribe((res) => {this.ticker = res;

  for(var j = 0; j<= this.coins.length-1; j++)
  {
    var currencyName: string = this.coins[j];
    if(this.ticker[currencyName])
    {
      var temp = [{name: currencyName, amount: this.ticker[currencyName].last} ]
      this.coinResults.push(temp)
    }
  }//end the for loop
  }); //end the subscribe function                                                       
 this.conversionService.getFullCurrencyExchange().subscribe( (res) => {this.currencyExchange = res["rates"]
  });
  console.log(this.coinResults);
}// End OnInit
```

Comment: update your post with the **resultsType** code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`coinResults` is declared as an array of `resultsType`, so it's `push` method would only accept arguments of `resultsType` type. However, you're trying to push **an array** of `resultsType` to `coinResults` (note the square brackets):

```typescript
// temp is resultsType[]
var temp = [{name: currencyName, amount: this.ticker[currencyName].last} ]
// but coinResults.push() accept only resultsType
this.coinResults.push(temp)
```

Loose the square brackets around the object literal in `var temp=...` line.

Answer (score 1):

you can't pass an array to `Array.push(array)` since Array.push signature defined as reset parameters `push(...items: T[])`, use Array.push(item) instead.

```
var temp = {name: currencyName, amount: this.ticker[currencyName].last}; 
this.coinResults.push(temp);
```

OR using spread operator:`...`

```
var temp = [{name: currencyName, amount: this.ticker[currencyName].last} ];
this.coinResults.push(...temp);
```